lipschitzness for the gradient of KL divergence $KL(P||Q_\phi)$ where $P$ is fixed and $Q$ is parameterized by $\phi$
I am considering KL divergence $\text{KL}(P||Q_\phi)$ between two continuous distributions $P$ and $Q$ where $P$ is fixed and $Q$ is a Gaussian parameterized by $\phi$. Is it possible to prove that the gradient of $\text{KL}(P||Q_\phi)$, $\nabla_\phi \text{KL}(P||Q_\phi)$ is $L$-lipschitz for some $L$?
Here $Q_\phi$ can be expressed as $N(\mu_\phi,\sigma_\phi^2)$. In the application I am considering, $\mu_\phi$ and $\sigma_\phi$ can be the output of a neural network.
What kind of additional assumption can we put on this problem to make it more tractable?

How is $Q$ parameterized? I imagine you would need at least $Q(\phi)$ to be Lipschitz

I just updated the question to describe more about $Q$.

My point is that if $\mu_\phi$ and $\sigma_\phi$ are outputs of a neural network, you have no guarantee they are Lipschitz. If you assume $\mu_\phi$ and $\sigma_\phi$ are Lipschitz, the steps Guillaume explained below should suffice.

The KL divergence between two Gaussians is explicit. I won't do the steps for you, but here is the skeleton.

First, become familiar with how to parameterize Gaussians, and to shifting between parameterizations. Observe that, without changing the KL divergence, we can change variables so that P has mean 0 and covariance the identity

Second, change variables again so that Q has diagonal covariance

Now, write the density of Q and compute the expected value of its logs: that's just the expected value of a second degree polynomial


The final formula is not particularly pretty, but it's not horrible either.
